# Why cant I pass a mongoose promise resolve as the handler for another promise onResolve

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

Working with Mongoose and mpromise, Im getting some odd behavior with callbacks.  Looking through the mpromise code for `Promise.prototype.onResolve` I don't see why the function isn't applying correctly.

```
var prom = new mongoose.Promise();
anotherPromise.onResolve(prom.resolve);
```

The onResolve of anotherPromise never seems to resolve, unless I throw it in an anonymouse function.

```
var prom = new mongoose.Promise();
anotherPromise.onResolve(function(err, doc) { prom.resolve(err, doc); });
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing `prom = anotherPromise` or `prom = anotherPromise.then()`?

Comment: yeah, I need to create a promise wrapper for `Model#save` as it does not return a promise. Im handling all the promises in my restify routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) matters. You're not passing the `resolve` method of that particular `prom`, but the generic one which is not bound to any promise and will not work when called with no (or the wrong) context.

In your anonymous function, you're explicitly invoking the method *on* the `prom` object. You also could've used [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
anotherPromise.onResolve(prom.resolve.bind(prom));
```

Comment: perfect. I was going to try binding it; totally makes sense, thanks for pointing this out!